# алгоритм пропорционального уменьшения изображения

Tags: php

здравствуйте, перед выводом изображений на своем сайте я делю максимальную длину блока куда будут выведены эти изображения, на количество изображений, то есть если 1 изображение то оно может занимать полную длину блока, если 2 то пополам, если 3 то 1/3, и так до 5. Размеры у изображений произвольные. так вот я столкнулся с проблемой, когда я обрезаю длину изображения, высота остается не тронутой, поэтому любой желающий может добавить картинку с огромной высотой, но маленькой длиной, тем самым подпортив вид сайта, как можно исправить такой недочёт? я могу конечно обрезать и высоту тоже , если она будет больше определенного числа, но тогда изображение будет выгледить не пропорционально

Comment: Уменьшение размера продумайте сами. Дело в том, что можно уменьшать картинку пропорционально, то есть определите что у вас должно быть фиксированным высота или ширина. Если картинки не пропорциональны, тогда корректно отображаться не будет. Либо обрезайте лишнее отбрасываение пикселей после уменьшения. 
<?php $n = count($images); <img height="<?= $max_height/$n ?>" src="...">
То есть максимальную высоту делите на текущее количество картинок

Comment: ой, то есть $width менять